# Change paragraph text dynamically with textarea by clicking third element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, click, textarea, paragraph

I want to display written textarea text in another textarea by clicking a third element.
So here's the code I'm using at the moment but it shows the written text when you press the **textarea**:

```
  $(function(){
    $('#text').click(function(){
      $('#preview').text($(this).val());
    });
  });
```

And here's the HTML part:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<textarea id="preview"></textarea>

<div id="show-text"></div>
```

So the idea is to display the text inside textarea#text in textarea#preview when you click div#show-text.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that your click event is registered on the textarea. What you're actually looking for is:

```
  $(function(){
     $('#show-text').click(function(){
       $('#preview').text($('#text').val());
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function in Javascript,that is adding data into the paragraph:

```
  <p id="textToAdd"></p>
    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        $('#textToAdd').innerHTML = $('#fname').value;
       
    }
    </script>
```