# change text between html tags that are inside a textarea jquery

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

How do I change the text between a html tag that has an id that is inside a text area using jQuery.

```
<textarea><div id="tochange">Text</div></textarea>
```

How do I change the "text" inside #tochange , of course this will be display as HTML code as it is in textarea.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982727/change-paragraph-text-dynamically-with-textarea-by-clicking-third-element-with-j

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('textarea').val( 
   $('<div />').append( $($('textarea').val()).text('something') ).html() 
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sDJxM/)

Comment: thanks. Just curious , what id there's two divs in the textarea?

Comment: @Ravensmith450 - you'd do that by just using basic jQuery selectors, here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sDJxM/1/)...

Comment: Hi thanks again , i put a normal text in , it went missing, the jquery is overwriting it with val `<textarea><div id="tochange">Text</div><div id="nochange">More Text</div>test</textarea>`

Comment: @Ravensmith450 - that's right, it uses jQuery to parse the HTML based on your question where the textarea only contains valid HTML, if you start mixing textnodes or invalid markup into the textarea, you would no longer have the luxury of using jQuery to parse it and select elements, you would have to use a regex instead, or create a more compilcated function that understands invalid markup and textnodes.